# Restrict API access to a single source IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

1. User visits my website, which is a static site on EC2.
2. On purchasing, after PayPal checkout, the index file on my site sends a request to an API server to get the zip file.
3. The API server, also on EC2, responds with the zip file and link.

I want to ensure that the API server / endpoint responds only if the request has come from my site’s index.html file but I cannot use Security Groups to filter out the IP— because when the call is made from index.html file, the originating IP is client's IP.

Comment: Can you defined what you mean by "coming from my website"? Is your website directly calling your API and processing the results?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Use a secret key or digitally sign your API request.

Comment: Since you have a static website, this means all code runs at the client. Any trick you impose, I can undo or forge in 60 seconds. You will need your website on a compute instance such as EC2, Elastic Beanstalk or a combination of Lambda & API Gateway. An exception might be (I don't use or develop with PayPal) is if you have access to a PayPal token (such as OAuth) that your API can validate.

Comment: Another method is to use Cognito to authenticate your clients. Then your API can validate the Cognito credentials.

Comment: @JohnHanley yeah true so cognito is also good method and easy to implement and authenticate user. impressed with idea

Comment: @JohnHanley Oh, ok sure. Let me try that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: As per @JohnHanley - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

Answer (score 1):

If your website is hosted on somewhere not on some EC2 and sending API request to your EC2 then you can use AWS security group for.

Define Security group with custom ip and port so only requests from that ip only goes into that particular EC2 and trigger your API.

in simple term :> Whatever ip your defining in security group that is only able to send request to ec2

Comment: The site is a static website which sends the request to the API server. So, the IP of the originating source is the IP of the user that has just purchased the good. The website is public, so I cant use security groups in this case.

Comment: @SujanSundareswaran - Your comment means that your website is not directly calling the API. Edit your question and fill in the details that you are leaving out.

Comment: @SujanSundareswaran i think you have to edit your question.

Comment: Ok, edited accordingly. I’m not an experienced dev, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible with IP filtering as you clearly identified, client IP changes since the request is coming from index.html.

If your motive is to reduce threats to your EC2 instance, use a web application firewall like AWS WAF to filter traffic sent to the EC2 instance.

Also configure CORS properly to prevent requests from any other origins.

Comment: Ashan, WAF is IP based, so this won't work to protect the API endpoint as the purchasing can arrive from any IP address. CORS is browser based, so a technology like CURL or just plain HTTP/S will bypass this. The key is authentication with signatures or tokens.

Comment: @John if it is to allow a success PayPal checkout to download a zipfile, it will require to implement the paypal checkout client integration.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#
I don't see a use case with IP filtering with AWS for this.

Comment: Ashan, I have to defer to you on PayPal as I have not had a chance to use their service. Given how large and popular PayPal ...